# missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed error while Sorting in R

Tags: r, sorting

```
arr1_ <- c(-4,44.7,-2,40,54,1,-3,4)
for(i in 1 : ceiling(length(arr1_))) {
  for(j in i+1 : ceiling(length(arr1_))){
   if(arr1_[i] > arr1_[j]){
      temp = arr1_[i]
      arr1_[i] = arr1_[j]
      arr1_[j] = temp
    }}}
```

Error in if (arr1_[i] > arr1_[j]) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Execution halted

Comment: Also, `length()` is always an integer, so the `ceiling()` is not needed.

Comment: there is a difference between `i+1:10` and `(i+1):10` eg let i<- 5 and you will see that You need the second and not the firs. That is because `:` has precedence over `+`. Use paranthesis

Comment: @akrun yes. OP needs to loop until `length(arr_1) - 1`

Comment: use `for(i in 1 : (length(arr1_) - 1)) {
  for(j in (i+1) : length(arr1_)){EVERYTHING ELSE HERE}}`